# implementing server-side after REQUEST sent

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, architecture, mongoose

Right now, i found out that if i were to put this url to my browser, a `.csv` file will be downloaded to my Downloads folder on My Computer, where the word `YHOO` is the stock symbol of Yahoo
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&d=0&e=28&f=2010&g=d&a=3&b=12&c=1996&ignore=.csv

Is there any way where I can implement the above action on my own personal-use RESTful website where

1. on a client-side GUI, the user inputs symbol
2. on client-side, a request URL is constructed with the symbol
3. client-side sends the request URL to the browser (similar to the action i described above)
4. browser downloads a file to a location on a server (dropbox / EC2)
5. `.csv` file is converted to `json` object on server
6. `json` object is returned to client

How can i do this, and which framework is recommended for high performance. i am thinking of NodeJS and Mongoose.

Comment: client-side sends to browser? huh?

Comment: where in the question is the confusion?

Comment: using the term "clientside" usually means "browser".

Comment: i'm not sure how to explain it well. what i'm trying to do is that behind the scenes, to emulate the same action but behind-the-scenes of sending a URL to a browser, and downloading the `.csv` file

Comment: if you click the link, it will download a `.csv` file. what i'm trying to do is to do that behind-the-scenes on another website which i will be building

Comment: Your architecture is confusing...

Comment: does this question boil down to "how can I return a .csv file from the server and have the browser display a 'Save As...' dialog?"

Comment: @ultranaut yes you're almost correct, its return a .csv file from a server in this case (icharts.yahoo.com) and save it in another server

Comment: you want to download the .csv file from Yahoo's (or whoever's) server and then upload it to your server?

Comment: @ultranaut, yes that's correct

Comment: and then your server converts it to a json object and returns that back to the client?

Comment: @ultranaut you got it, thing is there may not be a Yahoo API to download that specific `.csv` file from yahoo server except by making a url and using a browser to point to that url to download it

Comment: I think you have a bit of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) happening here.

Comment: @ultranaut okay, scrap my suggested solution of nodeJS and etc. What is a good solution then

Comment: @limelights answer below seems to be along the lines of what you're after: tell **your** server what the resource you want is, let it make the request to **their** server, convert the response to json and send it back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question like this:

1. on a browser or GUI, the user inputs symbol
2. on server-side, a request URL is constructed with the symbol
3. server-side sends the request URL to the above url (similar to the action i described above)
4. server-side downloads a file to a location on the server or remote repository(dropbox / EC2)
5. .csv file is converted to a json object on the server
6. the server then returns the json object is returned to the browser or GUI

If so, then the answer to your question is yes, this is possible albeit a bit tricky if you want to to work properly.
This doesn't have to be Node.js specific. You don't need Node.js nor Mongoose for this since you're not saving the CSV to the harddrive but just going to be an interrim transporter.

Basically you can in your "servlet" issue a POST call to another url and fetch the CSV file.

Then convert this and write the file on the response and serve it back to the client.